# Avoid else-if statement with cast

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, casting

I have several java classes `Cat`, `Dog`, `Lion`, etc that extend class abstract class `Animal`. And these classes have different attributes. For example

Cat has attributes X1, X2. Dog has attributes X3, X4 etc. Data types X1, X2, X3 and X4 are completely different

Now I have an array of Animals (`animals`) and I want to iterate through this array and map every animal (dog, cat, etc) to a `Record` class.

Currently I am doing it this way

```
 for (Animal animal : animals){  
  Record record = new Record();  
    if (animal instance of Dog){ 
      record.setAttribute1 ((Dog)animal.getX1()); 
      record.setAttribute2 ((Dog)animal.getX2())
    }
    if (animal instance of Cat){  
      record.setAttribute3 ((Dog)animal.getX3());   
      record.setAttribute4 ((Dog)animal.getX4())
    }    

    etc  
 }
```

this is design ill because of the long if-else chain and the dynamic cast

Is there a way to avoid these 2 problems. Appreciate your help

Comment: is X1 and x2 atterbuite has same data type of atterbuite x3 and x4  or what it's their data type? another way can not the record constructor has overloded version that accept cat and another one that accept dog and so on and in the constructor you do the instailizations of record atterbuite

Comment: updated the answer. Data types are completely different

Comment: then you can check the link by John or the answer below or if it possible to overload the record constructor as mentioned earlier also check those design pattern https://java-design-patterns.com/ using java

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to let each `Animal` map itself to `Record`:

```
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract Record makeRecord();
    ... // other methods
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    public Record makeRecord() {
        ... // map the Cat to Record
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    public Record makeRecord() {
        ... // map the Dog to Record
    }
}
```

This lets you avoid the cast, because each class knows how to handle its own attributes.